# Firebase Authentication Server Error

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting the following error:

```
For a custom firebase host you must first set your authentication 
server before using authentication features!
```

My Code:

```
public void initialize() throws IOException {

    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("/Users/ryan/dev/uandmemelogin/src/main/java/rgross/kmccann/firebase.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://uandmeme-57321.firebaseio.com/")

            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    firebase.createUser("rgross", "ser", new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) {
            System.out.println("Worked");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? I've followed the documentation, but I'm still struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you used the wrong URL when you initialized the Firebase connection.

Be sure that it is in this format:

ObjectiveC

```
Firebase *myRootRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com"];
```

Comment: I followed this, but it doesn't recognize any database. I'm going to look into Android native for this, as it meshes a lot better with Firebase.